# Selenium Ide: use regex in xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, ide, click

i  have this

```
clickAndWait |//img[contains(@alt,'a string (2013) other string')]|
```

i want to add regex to  have this

```
clickAndWait |//img[contains(@alt,'any text (any date) any other text')]|
```

Any help?

Comment: When you say "any date", do you mean a year only?

Comment: and do you mean that you don't care what text comes before/after the date? Or are you trying to match a particular start/end string?

Comment: in fact ,i want  just to include Any regular expression
for example: with this:[0-9]{4}
 my dicciculty is how to include  this  regular expression in this snippet
i thought  about this
clickAndWait |//img[contains(@alt,regexpi:[0-9]{4})]|
 but it don't work